# What is the largest (if any) multiplicative modulo group with all prime elements?

Tags: finite-groups, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, multiplicative-function

Here's what I've been able to find out so far to address this question:

1) $C^*_2$ = {1}, $C^*_3$ = {1, 2}, $C^*_4$ = {1, 3}, $C^*_6$ = {1, 5}, $C^*_8$ = {1, 3, 5, 7}, and $C^*_{12}$ = {1, 5, 7, 11}, $C^*_{18}$ ={1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17}, and $C^*_{30}$ = {1, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29} are all prime.

2) All $C^*_p$ where p is a prime larger than 3 have {4} as an element and thus cannot be all prime.

What is the largest modulo multiplicative group with all primes or is that even possible and there is no "largest"?

Comment: Which composite element of $\mathbb Z_{30}^\times$ have you found? Numbers with a factor of $2$, $3$, or $5$ are not coprime to $30$, so the smallest composite number that _is_ coprime to $30$ is $7^2=49$.

Comment: Thank you, let me update the question to make it more in line with what I'm after

Answer (score 1):

**$n=30$ is the largest $n$ with this property.**

Note that $11^2 < 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$. By induction it is now straightforward to prove that if $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime, then $p_{n+1}^2 < 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdot p_{n-1} \cdot  p_n$ for $ n \geq 4$. Indeed, the induction step follows from the fact that $p_{n+1}$ is larger than $(p_{n+2}/p_{n+1})^2$, which is at most $4$ by Bertrand's postulate.

Let $p_k$ be the smallest prime not dividing $n$. Then $p_k^2$ is composite and coprime to $n$, so if $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ contains only primes then $p_k^2 > n \geq p_{1} p_2 \cdots p_{k-1}$, which implies $k \leq 4$ and $n < 7^2$. So if $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\ast$ contains only primes, then $n$ is at most $48$.

It is now easy to check that $30$ is the largest number with this property, since any number between $30$ and $48$ is coprime to $4$, $9$ or $25$.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I was looking for and you make it look easy!  If interested in a followup, the reason I ask is because I want to know if there is a connection between this n=30 result and a different n=24 result: the only elements of $C^*_m$ that are all self-inverse are the divisors of 24: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24 (OEIS A018253; Eggar 2000). And with the only all prime groups are +/-6 from both 12 and 24, from C2xC2 and C2xC2xC2,   I would find it most interesting if a limit of prime elements could be related to a limit on symmetry groups within the multiplicative modulo groups

Answer (score 1):

We're looking for numbers $m$ such that every composite number less than $m$ is coprime to $m$.

If $p$ is the smallest prime that does *not* divide $m$, then $p^2$ is composite and coprime to $m$, so if $p^2<m$, then $m$ doesn't work.

Now turn that around and choose $p$ first. Since $p$ is the *smallest* prime that doesn't divide $m$, we can see that $m$ has to be at least the product of all primes smaller than $p$. But then, for $p=11$ we see that this smallest $m$ is already too large -- and due to Bertrand's postulate, this will keep holding for $p>11$ (namely, the product of the two last primes before $p$ is at least $p^2/8$, and multiplying this by the three first primes produces something that exceeds $p^2$). So the possibilities are:

- $p=7$ and $m$ is a multiple of $30$ less than $49$ -- that is $m=30$.
- $p=5$ and $m$ is a multiple of $6$ less than $25$ -- that is, $m\in \{6, 12, 18, 24\}$.
- $p=3$ and $m$ is an even number less than $9$ that is not a multiple of $3$ -- that is, $m\in\{2, 4, 8\}$.
- $p=2$ and $m$ is odd and less than $4$ -- that is, $m=3$.

This is the complete set of qualifying $m$s, so the maximum is $m=30$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!  I appreciate and am amazed at the seemingly many different ways that can be taken to approach a question.

Answer (score 1):

**Claim.** For $n>30$, there always exists a composite $m$ with $1<m<n$ and $\gcd(n,m)=1$.

*Proof.* If $n$ is odd, we can take $m=4$.
If $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, we can take $m=9$.
If $n$ is not a multiple of $5$, we can take $m=25$.
So assume $n$ is a multiple of $30$. In particular, $n\ge 60$.
Thus if $n$ is not a multiple of $7$, we can take $m=49$.
So now we may assume $n$ is a multiple of the first four primes.
In particular, $n\ge 210$.
Thus if $n$ is not a multiple of $11$, we can take $m=11^2$.
And if $n$ is not a multiple of $13$, we can take $m=13^2$.
So now we may assume $n$ is a multiple of the first six primes.
In particular, $n\ge 30030$.
This allows us to repeat the argument with $17^2$, $19^2$, and so on up to $173^2=29929$.

A pattern evolves!
Let $p$ be the smallest prime with $p\nmid n$. As seen, $p>173$.

By Bertrand, there is a prime $q$ between $\frac{p-1}2$ and $p$; note that $q\ge89$.
By Bertrand again, there is a prime $r$ between $\frac{q-1}{2}$ and $q$; note that $r\ge 47$.
Thus $n\ge 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot r\cdot q>4r\cdot 2q>p^2$ and so we can take $m=p^2$ - contradiction.
 $\square$

Comment: Thank you so much!  To be clear as I'm no mathematician, this is proof by contradiction yes?  I want to be sure as I study your proof.